# OMNeT++ INET Parse error in match expression

Tags: parsing, graphics, omnet++, inet

I downloaded to the latest version of OMNeT++ (omnnetpp-6.0pre10) with the latest version of INET (inet4.3) in order to find out if some problems with the inet4.2.1 version would be solved.
However, after the installation I tried to start a tutorial simulation that comes with all INET stuff (I run WirelessA.ned file inside inet/tutorials/wireless) and I got this error:

```
<!> Error: Parse error in match expression: syntax error
```

This shows up before the simulation starts, in the console, and the Qtenv graphical environment doesn't open. Here I'll leave the complete code I see in the console:

```
Starting...

$ cd C:/omnetpp/omnetpp-6.0pre10/samples/inet/tutorials/wireless
$ ../../../../bin/opp_run.exe -m -c Wireless01 -n ../../src;../../examples;..;../../showcases -x inet.emulation;inet.showcases.visualizer.osg;inet.showcases.emulation;inet.clock.common;inet.clock.model;inet.visualizer.osg;inet.examples.voipstream;inet.clock.oscillator;inet.examples.emulation;inet.transportlayer.tcp_lwip;inet.applications.voipstream;inet.clock.base;inet.examples.clock;inet.transportlayer.tcp_nsc --image-path=../../images -l ../../src/INET omnetpp.ini

OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2020 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 6.0pre10, build: 201218-d9021c6e4d, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer

Setting up Qtenv...

Loading NED files from ../../src:  997
Loading NED files from ../../examples:  181
Loading NED files from ..:  20
Loading NED files from ../../showcases:  43

Loading images from 'C:\omnetpp\omnetpp-6.0pre10\samples\inet\images': *: 0  3d/*: 0  background/*: 1  block/*: 2  misc/*: 218  showcases/*: 9 
Loading images from 'C:\omnetpp\omnetpp-6.0pre10\images': *: 0  abstract/*: 90  background/*: 4  block/*: 320  device/*: 195  logo/*: 1  maps/*: 9  misc/*: 70  msg/*: 55  old/*: 111  status/*: 28 


<!> Error: Parse error in match expression: syntax error


End.
```

I think this has to do with the graphical part of the simulation, since I found this: [Parse Error](https://gitter.im/omnetpp/community?at=5ce82fbd83ae782aeec43748).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the `.qtenvrc` file from your home directory. That file may contain filter expressions that are no longer valid in OMNeT++ 6. (Check also the root of your project, and the current working directory for the file)

Comment: Thanks. Btw I reinstalled OMNeT++ 6.0pre10 on another computer, opened INET following step by step the installer documentation inside INET, and started OMNeT++ from the mingw shell using Run as administrator option, and the problem was gone.